# Specify async attribute to javascript with HAML

Tags: javascript, ruby, haml, middleman

In order to include google analytics in a web page generate

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-135345611-1">
```

I couldn't find that much in the [docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter).  Then I found [this](http://www.htmltohaml.com/), but it converted my HTML tags to

```
%script(:async => "", src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-135345611-1")
```

which failed the middleman v4.2.1 build with:

```
Invalid attribute list: "(:async => \"\", src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-135345611-1\")".
partials/_header.html.haml:4
```

Anyone know how to write this line in HAML so it parses correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
%script{:async => "", :src => "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-135345611-1"}
```

When I ran your code through that site it wrapped it with brackets rather than parens. Maybe that's why it's not parsing correctly?

On a side note, I personally use https://html2haml.herokuapp.com/ since it's using the same version of haml that middleman uses.

Answer (score 1):

To render HTML attributes without attributed values, like `async` or `selected`, scroll to "Boolean attributes" at http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#attributes.

So, to include your GA code, use:

```
%script{async: true, src: "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-135345611-1"}
```